# What does "more than I gave" mean in "I therefore named a price which was £500 more than I gave"?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, arthur-conan-doyle, sherlock-holmes

I’d like to ask about the sentence from *The Three Gables* by Conan Doyle.

> .. but naturally I was interested in what he said. I therefore named a
> price which was ***£500 more than I gave***.

Here I’m not really sure about what the speaker meant. The speaker is talking about when someone wanting to buy her house came to her. I’d like to make sure whether the price mentioned by her was..

- A: The one £500 higher than the price she bought the house she lives in now.

Or..

- B: The one £500 higher than the lowest figure on which she would have accepted to sell the house.

I don’t know how to interpret the verb “give” in the quote. I think “to give” can mean both “to concede” and “to pay”, right? Which one is it?

Comment: Sure, but when talking about transactions with money, "give" meaning concede is a bit too lyrical and far-fetched than the simplest meaning of giving money.

Comment: I don't think it's either - it's "C. she named a sum of money that was £500 more than the price she paid for the house she was living in at the time" - i.e. the house that the other person was trying to buy. She could well have been doing herself out of a large amount of money if she'd lived there 40 years, but as she'd been there only a short time, and considering the value of a British house at the time, adding £500 on top of the ~£500 she probably paid for it was a good test of just how committed the other person was to buying a house at double the going market rate

Answer (score 24):

It helps to have a bit more of the context leading up to this:

> There have been some very strange happenings. I have been in this house more than a year now, and as I wished to lead a retired life I have seen little of my neighbours. Three days ago I had a call from a man who said that he was a house agent. He said that this house would exactly suit a client of his, and that if I would part with it money would be no object. It seemed to me very strange as there are several empty houses on the market which appear to be equally eligible, but naturally I was interested in what he said. I therefore named a price which was five hundred pounds more than I gave.

From this, it's apparent that the speaker is saying he named a price which was five hundred pounds more than he had paid for the house himself. The wording is a bit odd, but likely an artifact of slightly different vernacular stylings in 1926 vs 2021.

Comment: Had it ended “…five hundred pounds more than I gave **for it**.”, then it would have been perfectly clear today — and not remotely odd (at least, not round these parts).  I guess the ‘for it’ should be implied by the context.

Comment: Not sure if it's just down to inflation or me not understanding British currency, but isn't a difference of £500 pretty near meaningless when you're talking about the price of a whole *house*, even back then?  I think you'd be looking at 5 figures on the low end (these days it'd be at least 6 figures I think), so going up or down by £500 seems like it'd hardly matter...

Comment: In 1926 [the average house in Britain cost £619.](https://www.standard.co.uk/homesandproperty/property-news/house-prices-the-average-home-has-risen-by-47-000-per-cent-in-the-queen-s-lifetime-a100376.html)

Comment: It's inflation at work. Housing prices in particular have gone up a great deal since the 1970s. My quick google search didn't reveal housing prices beyond the extreme high end for England in the 1920s (although one passing mention indicated a cottage might go for £420), but the average weekly wage was £5 which translates to an annual income of about £250 which helps put the numbers in context.

Comment: I still have the receipted invoice from when my late grandfather married and moved into a new small house in the UK in 1913 (admittedly a bit earlier than 1926). The cost of a complete basic set of furniture for kitchen, living room and a bedroom, cooking equipment, curtains, etc, was just £20. He paid in cash, in two installments. And interestingly, he bought *everything* from just one store, in the nearest small town - "small" meaning population about 2,500.

Comment: Yes, but you have to balance it up that in 1926 was a whole different era in terms of the relative value of money. A fireman would probably earn £10 a month, so it would be 4 months wages to kit out a house. It probably still is 4 months of a fireman's wages to kit out a house ..

Comment: @DarrelHoffman not relevant, but even today there are taxes which only kick over a certain value, or government bonus schemes that are only valid below a price. For those the difference between £399.5k and £400k will be very significant!

Comment: According to the Bank of England inflation calculator £500 in 1926 is equivalent to £31,254.05 in 2020 - house price inflation has been much higher than general inflation

Comment: So, did he sell the house?

Comment: @HannoverFist You'll find out in 2023-01, when *The Case-Book of Sherlock Holmes* becomes out of copyright so you'll no doubt find the full text on the internet; or sooner if you loan a copy from a library.

Comment: @b_jonas The story is from 1926, so it went into the public domain in the US at the start of the year; it's also been PD for a few years in the EU/UK and for a few decades in Canada, so it's out there now.

Comment: @HannoverFist prosafilaes is correct and I was off by one year. The text of this story is now in public domain, and you can read it at https://en.wikisource.org/?curid=3890035 .